# Double orthogonal complement of non-degenerate bilinearform

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a question:

Let's start with a non-degenerate bilinearform $\beta$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. For a subvectorspace $W\subset V$ let

$W^{\perp}=\{v\in V|\beta(v,w)=0\ \textrm{for all } w\in W\}$

Now I've read the statement, that $(W^{\perp})^{\perp}=W$. I only produced a proof for $\beta$ reflexiv.
Is the more general statement true? If yes: How do you prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This statement is in general wrong if you don't consider reflexive bilinearforms. An easy counterexample on $\mathbb R^2$ is the following bilinearform:
$$M := \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&1 \end{pmatrix} \quad , \quad (x,y) \mapsto x^t M y$$

Since $M$ is invertible this is non-degenerate. Now consider $W:=<\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}>$:

\begin{align*}
W^\perp=Ker(x \mapsto x^t \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix})=<\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}>=:U\\
U^\perp=Ker(x \mapsto x^t \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix})=<\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}> \neq W
\end{align*}

Greets to Tübingen from Saarbrücken!